# In C, does (x==y==z) behave as I'd expect?

Tags: c, equality

Can I compare three variables like the following, instead of doing `if((x==y)&&(y==z)&&(z=x))`? [The if statement should execute if all three variables have the same value. These are booleans.]

```
if(debounceATnow == debounceATlast == debounceATlastlast)
{
 debounceANew = debounceATnow;
}
else
{
 debounceANew = debounceAOld;
}
```

Comment: -1 for not spending 30 seconds writing a test program to find out.

Comment: ./shrug
I'm more interested in understanding why it doesn't work. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

***No, it does not.***

`x == y` is converted to int, yields `0` or `1`, and the result is compared to `z`. So `x==y==z` will yield true if and only if  `(x is equal to y and z is 1) or (x is not equal to y and z is 0)`

What you want to do is

```
if(x == y && x == z)
```

Comment: I almost think gcc should generate a warning for this, but then again if you write `x==y==z` it seems to indicate that either you don't know C at all or you're a god of code golf...

Comment: When compiled with `-Wall`, gcc does produce a warning for such a construct:  `warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of ‘==’`

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan Didn't realize I could do that.

Comment: @R.., regarding golfing: `x^y^z` is shorter by two characters.

Comment: @A.Rex: yes, but it's not the same as `x==y==z`, as Armen pointed out. I figure the only use of `x==y==z` might be some obscure code-golf where `z` is actually a boolean value... :-)

Comment: @R..: I mean that `x==y==z` is the same as `x^y^z` if `x`, `y`, and `z` are boolean (the OP's context), or otherwise known to equal 0 or 1 already.

Answer (score 6):

No. The equality check associates from the left and the logical result is compared as a number, so that the expression `2 == 2 == 1` parses as `(2 == 2) == 1`, which in turn gives `1 == 1` and results in `1`, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually type something like this:

```
int main()
{
        const int first = 27,
                  second = first,
                  third = second,
                  fourth = third;
        if (!((first & second & third) ^ fourth))
            return 1;
        return 0;
}
```